# how to make a contractable stackpanel in Xaml

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

My idea is fairly simple and I've seen it many places. 
I want to be able to expand and contract a list of items based on a click on a button.

ex

- listitem 1
- listitem 2

  - subList item 1
  - subList item 2
- listItem 3

simply click Listitem 2 and the sublistitems should disapear. click it again or any other listitem and the sublist item belonging to that listitem should reappear.

here is what I've done so far(Doesn't work)

Channels.Xaml:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="InternetRadio.RadioChannels"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:InternetRadio"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">


<StackPanel x:Name="stationList" Orientation="Vertical">
    <Button x:Name="HamburgerButton" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE700;" Width="50" Height="50" Background="Transparent" Click="HamburgerButton_click"/>

    <TextBlock x:Name="textBox" Text="Internet Radio Stations" Padding="50,0,0,0" Height="20px" />
    <ToggleButton x:Name="collapsableBtn" Content="DR Channels" Margin="50,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" Click="collapsableBtn_Click" />

        <StackPanel x:Name="RadioChannelsCollapsable" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="tStack" Grid.Column="1" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding ItemName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Channels.xaml.cs

```
private void collapsableBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(RadioChannelsCollapsable.Visibility == Visibility.Collapsed)
            {
                RadioChannelsCollapsable.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                RadioChannelsCollapsable.Children.ToList().ForEach(vis => vis.Visibility = Visibility.Visible);
            }
            else
            {
                RadioChannelsCollapsable.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                RadioChannelsCollapsable.Children.ToList().ForEach(vis => vis.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed);
            }
```

just to be clear this usercontrol is used like this in a splitView:
mainpage.xaml

```
<SplitView x:Name="radioChannelssplitview" DisplayMode="CompactOverlay" IsPaneOpen="False" CompactPaneLength="50" OpenPaneLength="250">
    <SplitView.Pane>
        <local:RadioChannels x:Name="myControl" Background="Gray"/>
    </SplitView.Pane>
    <SplitView.Content>
        <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

            <TextBlock x:Name="StationTitle" Text="Internet Radio" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20px" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ProgramTitle" Text="Welcome Page" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20px" Margin="130,60,140,560" />
        </Grid>
    </SplitView.Content>
</SplitView>


        }
```

and I cannot make it work :( the splitview opens and closes easily but the stackpanel does not expand and contract at all. please give me a pointer to where or why I'm wrong and/or a pointer to how I should be doing this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather try to create my own UserControl that can be expaned or not depending on it's VisualState. My quick and simple sample:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MyItemTemplate">
        <local:MyItem></local:MyItem>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyItemTemplate}" 
              SelectionMode="None" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xamls.cs:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items.Add(new MyItemViewModel("Item1"));
        Items.Add(new MyItemViewModel("Item2"));
        Items.Add(new MyItemViewModel("Item3"));
    }

    public ApplicationDataLocality ApplicationDataLocalityEnum { get; } =
           ApplicationDataLocality.Local;

    public FontStyle FontStyleEnum { get; } =
               FontStyle.Normal;

    public ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel>();
}
```

MyItem.xaml.cs:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" x:Name="TitleBlock"  Tapped="Title_OnTapped"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" x:Name="ItemsBlock" ItemClick="Items_OnItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True"/>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Regular">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ItemsBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" >
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</StackPanel>
```

MyItem.xaml.cs:

```
public enum MyItemState
{
    Regular,
    Expanded
}

public sealed partial class MyItem : UserControl
{
    private MyItemState _state;
    public MyItemState State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set
        {
            _state = value;
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, _state.ToString(), true);
        }
    }

    public MyItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        State = MyItemState.Regular;
    }

    private void Title_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (State == MyItemState.Regular)
        {
            State = MyItemState.Expanded;
        }
        else
        {
            State = MyItemState.Regular;
        }
    }

    private void Items_OnItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        // action after subitem is clicked
    }
}
```

and MyItemViewModel:

```
public class MyItemViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TextBlock> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TextBlock>();

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public MyItemViewModel(string title)
    {
        Title = title;

        Items.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "SubItem1" });
        Items.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "SubItem2" });
        Items.Add(new TextBlock() { Text = "SubItem3" });
    }
}
```

whenever you click on the MyItem Title it will change it's state - to expand or shrink it's subItems (only TextBoxes just to keep it simple - may by antoher UserControl with any view you want) that in this case I store in another ListView.
ToDo: change the styles and animations so the state change may look better and so on.

Comment: looks very good. and it will probably be what I will end up with. 
However I'm sad to see that such a little and to my opinion common feature requires so much work.
Currently I was trying to make a quick and dirty mock-up to show the feasibility of my project. so not so much with view model and most of my stuff simply just happens in the code behind file instead of in an actual layered approach. I would had liked if I could had just made something like  in Jquery. : 
$(selector).hide(speed,callback);

$(selector).show(speed,callback);

Comment: I'll leave this open for now in the vane hope that a more simple solution arises next week I'll close it with or without a more simple solution

Comment: I ended up making most of the menu in the view model using your approach mostly :) still quite annoyed that something so simple have to be so expensive to make..

Comment: It's just how MVVM looks like. It may look over-complicated but trust me - it is very simple. Just need a lot of typing - but the idea is simple, just need to get used to it and see it's advantages (for example it's very easy to change layout without touching the code with logics and vice versa). Trust me, I am an engineer ;)

Comment: I personally prefer the MVC model.
the reason I find it over-complicated is because the menu structure and how it acts is something I strongly feel belongs in the view not in the view model. something as simple as the jquery for ASP.NET can do this with 3-4 lines of code..