# UWP Listview with expandable items

Tags: list, listview, uwp, expandablelistview

I have searched a lot on internet about how to build a ListView with grouped items in it(header and subitems) but i did not manage to find a good documentation.
Found something [here](https://sanje2v.wordpress.com/2016/03/30/uwp-custom-control-expandable-row-listview) or [here](https://github.com/nor0x/UWP_Expander) but something goes wrong...So the question is: is there a best practice for building that kind of ListView? Any official guidelines? I see, Windows 10 makes use of that control. Any thoughts of providing it with the SDK?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325340/how-to-make-a-contractable-stackpanel-in-xaml/39328006#39328006

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make a contractable stackpanel in Xaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39325340/how-to-make-a-contractable-stackpanel-in-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

You can also choose to use some third-party libraries. E.g, [How to Use Expandable List Items in Windows Store Apps](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/expander-for-universal-windows-apps)

You will see its source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/telerik/win8-xaml-sdk/tree/master/Blogs/ExpanderControl) as described in that blog.